# Object-oriented design pattern for object converter

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I was wondering what the best **OOP design pattern** should be put in place for my scenario.

**The scenario:**

I have two classes, ClassA & ClassB. I want to convert ClassA into a new ClassB, however, ClassA may change its member variables & methods. This means that one may have to update the way ClassA is translated into ClassB.

What would be the best OOP design to go about facilitating this translation from ClassA to a new ClassB?

**The goal:**

Create a design pattern that will allow to easily change the way ClassA will be translated to ClassB.

**Example:**

ClassA

```
public class ClassA {
    private String actionName;

    // With some getters & setters
}
```

ClassB

```
public class ClassB {
    private String action; // Note the subtle difference

    // With some getters & setters
}
```

Handler

```
public class Handler {
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();

    // Convert ClassB to ClassA

    This.publish(ClassA);
}
```

Comment: Could you just use a constructor like public ClassA(ClassB b) {...}?

Comment: You might be interested in a reflection in case of dynamic changes. However, would you provide an example anyway?

Comment: Just use mapstruct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a type that has a knowledge of all the members of both ClassA and ClassB. It is a bad idea to couple either ClassA or ClassB to each other, so you would normally see a third type that implements an interface like this:

```
interface Converter<T, R> {
  R convert(T obj);
}
```

You could implement this interface for your classes:

```
class AtoBConverter implements Converter<ClassA, ClassB> {
  public ClassB convert(ClassA obj) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This assumes that ClassA has public methods that allow you to examine its state and ClassB has a constructor/setters that allow you to modify its state. Strictly speaking if all three classes are in the same java package you could have those methods/constructors declared package private.

Comment: This seems like to best solution, is there any design patterns that may loosely tie inito this concept?

Comment: The Converter<T,R> interface is actually the same as Java's Function<T,R>  interface. Since this is a functional interface you can also implement this with a lambda and use it with "map" on streams. Function<T,R> has some additional higher order functions to join with other functions.

Answer (score 0):

use constructor with params (ClassA) for ClassB and vise versa

```
ClassA(ClassB object){
...
}
```

Comment: This is an option, but it would require writing a crazy long constructor for a ClassA object & I want to avoid that.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it couples ClassA and ClassB. I would definitely go for solution proposed by LeffeBrune

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely opt for a separate handler class to deal with this conversion.

As a little optimization, you could have static api's on this handler class so that whenever you wish to perform a conversion between two objects you don't have to instantiate an instance of the handler class as well.

For example:

Say you need to convert an object of Type A to an object of Type B.
Your converter could look like

```
class AToBConverter {
    
   public static B convert(A objA){
       //business logic to convert objA to objB
       return objB;
   } }
```

The advantage here is that whenever you need to convert object of type A to B you can simply do :

```
B objB = AToBConverter.convert(objA); //Note how we don't need to create an instance of the converter
```

Comment: It would be better to add some examples.